# When does a car engine do more work? From still to 50kmh or from 50kmh to 100 kmh

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, kinematics

> A car accelerates from rest to 50 km/hr and then from 50 km/hr to 100
>   km/hr. Assume there is no air drag.

In which case does the engine of the car do more work?

Comment: Hint: Work out the difference in kinetic energy to see the difference in work.

Comment: When calculating how much **work was done**, the really easy way to do it is to calculate the amount of energy that an object has **before** then work was done on it, and then calculate the amount of energy the object has **after** work was done on it. The difference in energy is the work that was done. Here you have two "before" states and two "after" states. do the "before and after" calculations for the first acceleration, and then the "before and after" for the second acceleration". The differences between these is the work that was done in the two cases. Compare them to get the answer.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Physics SE! Please note that [homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/50583) and [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/50583) are generally considered off-topic here. We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and prefer *conceptual* questions. Can you try making a question about some concepts that you'd need to solve this problem?